# can a group with non-trivial center be isomorphic to a normal subgroup of its group of automorphisms?

Tags: group-theory, proof-verification

i think (tho would be grateful for error-check) that the line of reasoning below suggests any group with trivial center is isomorphic to a normal subgroup of its automorphism group.

**question** does the converse hold? i.e. if a group is isomorphic to a normal subgroup of its automorphism group must it have a trivial center? and if not what is the most instructive counter-example?

(i) for a group $G$, its center $Z(G)$ is the kernel of a homomorphism $\phi: G \to A(G)$ of $G$ to its group of automorphisms, where the action of $\phi$ is defined by:
$$\forall x \in G, \phi(g)(x)=g^{-1}xg$$

thus if $Z(G)=\{1\}$ we have $\phi(G) \cong G$

(ii) if $a$ is any element of $A(G)$ and $\nu \in A(G)$ is the inner automorphism of $G$ corresponding to $n \in \phi^{-1}(\nu)$ then 
$$
\begin{align}
\nu^a(g) &= a^{-1}\nu a(g) \\
 &=a^{-1}(n^{-1}a(g)n) \\
&=a^{-1}(n^{-1})a^{-1}(a(g))a^{-1}(n) \\
& =a^{-1}(n^{-1}) g (a^{-1}(n^{-1}))^{-1} \\
& = g^{n^*} \\
&=\nu^*(g)
\end{align}
$$
where $n^* $ is the element of $g$ defined by ${n^*}^{-1}= a^{-1}(n^{-1})$ and $\nu^*=\phi(n^*)$

thus $$\phi(G) \triangleleft A(G)$$

Comment: The overall claim in both parts is correct, but execution needs some work. First of all, $\phi$ isn't actually a group homomorphism; it reverses the order of multiplication. To make it a group homomorphism you need to define $\phi(g)(x) := gxg^{-1}$ instead. For (ii), I'm not entirely sure what you mean by "$\nu \in A(G)$ is the inner automorphism of $G$ corresponding to $n \in  \phi^{-1}(\nu)$", but what you need to show is that for $a \in A(G)$ and $\nu \in A(G)$ an inner automorphism, $a\nu a^{-1}$ is also an inner automorphism.

Comment: @Dustan thx re your question about what i mean, my intention was to say that $n$ is a representative of the inner automorphism denoted by $\nu$. re $\phi$ i did notice that we have $\phi(gh)x = (gh)^{-1}xgh = h^{-1}(g^{-1}xg)h = \phi(h)(\phi(g)(x))$. is this a terminal obstacle, or can you suggest how i should proceed?

Comment: I already gave my suggestion for that issue. It's not a serious obstacle on account of the fact that every group is isomorphic to its opposite group via the map $g \mapsto g^{-1}$ anyway; it's just more standard to approach this issue by setting things up so that they are actually group homomorphisms rather than "anti"-homomorphisms.

Comment: and now that I understand what that line in (ii) means, your proof of (ii) looks perfect to me.

Comment: To hint at a standard result that you're touching against, you might figure out more generally what the map $\phi$ tells you even when $G$ doesn't have trivial center (specifically, what is its image isomorphic to?). Regarding actually answering your other question, try figuring out what you can embed into $$A\left(\bigoplus_{i=1}^\infty \mathbb Z\right).$$

Comment: that is a mind-broadening example! i see the involvement of an abelian group based on an infinite set of involutions, and the normal subgroup of the permutation group $S_{\omega}$ consisting of permutations which leave a cofinite set invariant

Answer (score 3):

The dihedral group of order $8$ has nontrivial centre and is isomorphic to its automorphism group, so it is certainly isomorphic to a normal subgroup thereof!

The dihedral group $G$ of order $16$ has automorphism group $A$ of order $32$, and $A$ has two normal subgroups isomorphic to $G$.

Comment: thx. simple, but instructive examples. i see the inner automorphisms of $D_8$ are isomorphic to the viergroup, but as yet i can't identify the required outer automorphism. could you offer a hint, which might also embolden me to look at $A(D_{16})$?