# generators of the automorphism group of $\bigoplus_{i=1}^\infty \mathbb{Z}$

Tags: group-theory

in [some helpful comments](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/886378/can-a-group-with-non-trivial-center-be-isomorphic-to-a-normal-subgroup-of-its-gr/#comment1829785_886378) recently Dustan Levenstein directed my attention to the automorphism group:
$$
A\left(\bigoplus_{i=1}^\infty \mathbb{Z}\right)
$$
i think the direct sum means that any automorphism projects to the identity on all but a finite number of the component copies of $Z$

my mind went first to the involutions of the components and to permutations of the components themselves. a little later i realized i had missed a lot out.

**question** is the following idea in the right direction?

each automorphism will be associated with a square matrix of integers with determinant $\pm 1$. however we cannot multiply matrices of different sizes, so the "matrix representation" will have to use infinite sequences $a=\{a_{mn}\}$ for each of which there is an integer $N$ such that:
$$
m \gt N \lor n \gt N \rightarrow a_{mn}=\delta_{mn}
$$ 
and the square matrix obtained by using the $a_{mn}$ with $m \le N$ and $n \le N$ must have determinant $\pm 1$.

**question** can the full group be generated by a subgroup isomorphic to the $2 \times 2$ matrices together with the subgroup which contains all permutations of finite subsets of components?

example: 
$$
\begin{align}
\begin{pmatrix} 3 & 5 & 0 \\ 4 & 7 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 3 & 2 \\ 0 & 7 & 5 \end{pmatrix}
& =
\begin{pmatrix} 3 & 15 & 10 \\ 4 & 21 & 14 \\ 0 & 7 & 5 \end{pmatrix}
= 
\begin{pmatrix} 7 & -5 & 0 \\ -20 & 15 & -2 \\ 28 & -21 & 3 \end{pmatrix}^{-1}
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Hmm. I have some reservations about the first paragraph. The elements of the direct sum $\bigoplus_{i=1}^\infty\Bbb{Z}$ do have the property that only finitely many of their components are non-zero. But I don't think that a general automorphism of this infinite product has such finiteness properties. For example any permutation of the (countably infinitely many) basis elements surely extends to an automorphism. In general I think you get something that could be described as $\infty\times\infty$ integer matrices with finitely many non-zero entries on each column. +1 for a good question.

Comment: thanks Jyrki. i see what you mean about the permutations.

Comment: what's easy to describe is the set of endomorphisms: these are infinite matrices in which each column is finitely supported (but rows may be infinitely supported). The automorphism group is the set of invertible such infinite matrices. To determine which matrices are invertible in a convenient way does not sound so obvious to me. Anyway it's unclear to me what the question precisely is.